# Why is the value of j in "j= 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5;" set to 2 and not 3?

Tags: c, switch-statement

In this program, `j` is assigned the value 2

```
j = 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5;
```

but if same expression is calculated with calculator it will come be 3.5 so in integer it will become 3.

I want to ask why `j` is assigned to 2? What am I missing?

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=0;
    int line=0;
    j = 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5;
    printf(" %d --------- \n", j);
    k -= --j;
    printf(" %d --------- \n", k);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        switch(i+k)
        {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            printf("\n %d", i+k);
            line++;
        case 3:
            printf("\n %d", i+k);
            line++;
        default:
            printf("\n %d", i+k);
            line++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n %d", line);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
2 --------- 
-1 --------- 

-1
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
10
```

Comment: Integer division vs floating-point division: 2*3/4 = 6/4 = 1. 8/5 = 1. 2.0 / 5 = 2.0 / 5.0 = 0.4. The value of the sum is 1 + 0.4 + 1 = 1.0 + 0.4 + 1.0 = 2.4. Conversion from float/double -> int is defined to truncate, discarding the fractional part: 2.4 -> 2.

Comment: Thanks, i was doing (2*3)/4 = 1.5, 2.0/5= 0.4 and 8/5= 1.6. 1.5+0.4+ 1.6=3.5 
That means .5 and .6 will be discarded even before addition.. Am i correct?

Comment: Note that because you do not have any `break;` statements in the `switch`, the iterations can print multiple copies of the output.  Also, it is generally best to end `printf()` format strings with a newline, rather than include them at the start.  The output may not appear until a newline is printed, so you may not see the last printing in a timely fashion.

Comment: The `(2 * 3) / 4` is evaluated to 1 because the computation is all integers; the `2.0 / 5` does evaluate to 0.4; the `8 / 5` is evaluated to 1 because it is all integers; the additions are then done in floating point and produces 2.4, but the assignment to `j` converts it back to an integer, which is 2.

Comment: Got to wonder why you're writing unclear code like this in the first place

Comment: @lightness because I am learning that's why :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
j= 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5;

2 * 3 / 4 Produce 1 -> it's integer
2.0 / 5 Produce 0.4 -> float
8/5 Produce -> 1.6 -> but in integer 1

Sum: 1 + 0.4 + 1 -> 2.4 -> converted to integer it's 2.
```

You have to typecast or say in other way it's float, 2 integers at dividing, produce integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now :)

Answer (score 4):

```
j= 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5;
```

`2 * 3 / 4` and `8 / 5` are integer divisions.

Use:

`2 * 3 / 4.0` and `8 / 5.0` to have floating point divisions.

Comment: as you said in USE: 
why 2*3/4 is floating point division why it is not integer division? 
It given only 4 whereas in other part 2.0/5 is given float that's why we are considering it floating point division.

Comment: @learner what I said is `2 * 3 / 4` is an integer division and why it is an integer division is because both operands of `/` operators (that is `2 * 3` and `4`) are integer expressions.

Comment: oh ok ok Sorry for the inconvenience. Now i got it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyse this step by step:

```
2*3/4 + 2.0 /5 + 8/5   // 8/5 gives 1, not 1.6 because it's integer division

 6/4  +  0.4   + 1     // 2.0/5 is float division, so decimal place is left

 1    +  0.4   + 1     // 6/4 gives 1, not 1.5 because it's integer division

        2.4

        2             //part after decimal point removed since j is int
```

Comment: Thanks alot, now that is correct explanation thanks a ton. Although i am not able to upvote your comment, sorry for that

Answer (score 2):

```
 2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8/5
```

`*` and  `/` are calculated before `+`and `-` which leasd to 3 1st steps:

1. integer calculation (as all operants as integer)

   ```
   2 * 3 / 4 = 6 / 4 = 1
   ```
2. floating point calculation (as at least one operant is floating point)

   ```
   2.0 / 5 = 2. / 5. = 0.4
   ```
3. integer calculation (as all operants as integer)

   ```
   8 / 5 = 1
   ```

Finally the result from (1. and 2. and 3.) is:

4. floating point calculation (as at least one operant is floating point)

   ```
   1. + 0.4 + 1. = 2.4
   ```

assigned to an integer (truncation downwards)

```
int j = 2.4
```

results in `j` being equal to `2`.